# Getting empty data when trying to access database from sqlserver using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am kind of new to vb.net... So please excuse me if its a noob question...
I have been trying to access data from database to create a crystal report..
Unfortunately, when am trying to access data from database, it returning nothing... At report.SetDataSource(ds), it returning an exception, that "the report have no tables..." I have searched a lot in the web.. but couldnt solve the issue...

Sample code is given below

```
 Using cs = New SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
            Dim sql = "select barcode from dbo.productrqst"
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, cs)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cs.Open()
            Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            Dim report As New RptProductRqst()
            report.SetDataSource(ds)
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: Your code looks OK to me, have you tried running the select statement on SSMS? Aslo, it's not wise to post your sa password anywhere, nor it is wise to use it for connecting to the database. I **strongly recommend** you to change that password ASAP (pick a strong password!) ,create a new sql server login that will have the minimal capabilities that is needed to your software, and use that sql server login instead of sa.

Comment: the connection string is not original...

Comment: Check your connectionString, this [LINK](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) might help

Comment: Nevertheless it's not a good choice to use sa account for connecting to the database. sa is like a god for sql server, it has way to much power to expose it to clients that might try using sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Nadeem_MK  i think thatz not the issue, since the cs.open() works well..

Comment: Did you try to run the select statement directly on SSMS? did you get the results back? How did you come to the conclusion that you don't get the results back in vb.net?

Comment: When i have tried to run the sql query in ssms, i got the data... But when I have tried to access the data using above code, i checked the datatable using the breakepoint....

Comment: I have edit the question with the exact problem...